# Code that rot13s the output when it is rot13'd

Tags: code-challenge

In case the title was confusing, I mean something like the following C code:

```
main(){}znva(){}
```

When rot13 encoded, the code becomes

```
znva(){}main(){}
```

and still runs.

But that isn't a valid answer, because of these rules:

- Your code must produce output. Code that doesn't produce output is disqualified.
- The program can't be empty. That's disqualified too.
- The program can't be the same or similar to the output. This means that you can't use Golfscript or PHP.

In a valid answer, the program produces some output without being rot13'd, such as:

```
Hello, World!
```

And when the program is rot13'd, the output changes to the following:

```
Uryyb, Jbeyq!
```

which is the rot13 of `Hello, World!`.

Have fun!

Comment: Is this code that produces an output when it is rot13'd? Or is it code that produces an output of itself rot13'd (that produces the original program)?

Comment: It sounds like the code is supposed to provide a rot13 filter when it is rot13ed, and it is supposed to output anything (non-empty) when run as-is. But this is interpolated from the vague suggestion of the title. Please provide a clear description of what the two versions of the program are supposed to actually do.

Comment: @breadbox I did that.

Comment: As it stands, the answer `A` in (say) PHP would meet the requirements.

Comment: @marinus Changed requirements to fix that.

Comment: You mean something (somewhat) similar to http://www.ioccc.org/1989/westley.c? (The program is explained in http://www.ioccc.org/1989/westley.hint)

Comment: Does the output have to contain letters? As it stands, `.` is a valid response in brainfuck.

Comment: "Simmilar to the output"? Does ruby fail that?

Comment: BTW: what is the objective winning criteria?

Comment: @tbodt In the future, please refrain from changing a challenge's rules and/or judging criteria once it's been posted. If you would like to "test out" a challenge before posting it, in order to per-determine what rule modifications might be necessary, please use the current Sandbox thread in Meta. (Currently at [Mk V](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/638/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-v).)

Comment: @lszj OK, I'll do what I can

Comment: -1 Congratulations. You now have successfuly created a chamelion quesion. The statement "assuming they [the rules] don't change again" only shows that you can't answer this without your answer beeing invalidated.

Comment: [I rolled back your questions, so the existing answers are (again) valid. You should probably ask a new question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43480/190161)

Comment: Also note that in your example the entire function `znva` is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby

Cheaty answer:

```
$><<'Hello, world!'
```

Slightly less cheaty answer:

```
s='Hello, world!'
$-I?puts(s):chgf(s)
```

Golf (15 chars)

```
$-I?p(:a):c(:a)
```

Comment: I changed the rules. Your second solution is the only one valid.

Comment: This is now a code golf contest. Shorten it up.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <s>25</s> <s>14</s> 12 characters

I believe this adheres to all of the requirements:

```
$_=a;fnl;say
```

Outputs `a`. After `rot13` the program looks like this:

```
$_=n;say;fnl
```

and outputs `n`.

Comment: Does perl generate an error on encountering `fnl`?

Comment: @tbodt Without strict mode (and warnings) turned on, Perl will parse `fnl` as `"fnl"` (i.e. as a string). The statement then becomes a no-op expression.

Comment: Your solution is not disqualified. And you get an up vote.

Comment: This is now a code golf contest. Shorten it up.

Answer (score 1):

### Brainf**k

Since you never said the output had to actually be affected by rot13, this is totally a valid answer:

```
-.
```

Not sure why it was downvoted, although it is kind of a cheap answer.

Comment: I changed the rules. histocrat's second solution is the only one valid.

Comment: add an letter at the end, and it will be valid.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Re-changed the rules. No comments. I think that I won't have to change them again.

Comment: You change the rules just to invalidate existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP 6

```
H<?//a
```

The program and its output differ by 83%, so not similar.
`a` is not transformed into output, should satisfy all rules now.

Comment: I changed the rules. histocrat's second solution is the only one valid.

Comment: Because chameleon question.

Comment: There I fixed it.

Comment: What does that `//` do? And don't you need a `?>` ending delimiter?

Comment: `//` is a comment. and no, I don't need an ending ?>

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 64 chars

```
_() { [[ "${1:0:1}" > U ]]&&rpub $@||echo $@; };_ Hello, Jbeyq.
```